# How to update a session attribute in Spring MVC web app

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I store a shopping cart instance during the checkout process in a session variable via org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes:

```
@SessionAttributes({"shoppingCart"})
public class CheckoutController { ... }
```

However, when the checkout process is completed I want to store a fresh new ShoppingCart instance in the session.

I need something like:

```
sessionAttributes.set("shoppingCart", new ShoppingCart());
```

Which method can I use to achieve this task?

Answer (score 4):

If you can access `HttpServletRequest`, try  with this

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("shoppingCart", new ShoppingCart());
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am 100% sure that my answer's way is working in my current live application without using and setting as `model attribute`. Do you think it can only be done as spring's **model attribute**?

Comment: @SergeBallesta You know we are learning ever, but I'm sorry about your previous comment of `Your answers adds a new attribute in the HttpSession but does not modify the model attribute.`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for your research, actually I just hold my working way. Thanks again for your sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Model` to override this:

```
public String method(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("shoppingCart", new ShoppingCart());
    ....
}
```

Another option would be `SessionStatus` interface added to method parameters. It has method to clean up session attributes:

```
public String method(SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That's what I do. See my answer above (should have been added after your post ...).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
Finally I solved the problem in the following way:
I have a base controller for all checkout related controllers which populates the shopping cart when a new session is created:

```
@SessionAttributes({"shoppingCart"})
public class CheckoutController {

  @ModelAttribute("shoppingCart")
  public ShoppingCart populateSessionShoppingCart() {
    // populates the cart for the first time if its null
    return new ShoppingCart();
  }
}
```

In the controller which completes the checkout process I use the following method:

```
@Controller
public class PaymentController extends CheckoutController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/final_page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String finalPage(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("shoppingCart", new ShoppingCart());
    return "final_page";
  }
}
```

The line: model.put("shoppingCart", new ShoppingCart()); resets the shopping cart in the session.

Note: This approach only uses the spring session handling which of course somehow also uses the underlying HttpSession. How spring handles session handling internally, is an internal spring implementation detail which is not relevant to the code above.